# List files not stored in Git repos

Tags: scripting, find, git

I want to find out what files in a certain directory are not managed by Git. This is so I because I use Git for backups, and I want to eventually get all my files personal in there.

What unix tool could accomplish this? Is there a way to use `find` to do this in a reasonably efficient way?

Example:

I have a folder where I store RFC-related stuff, it looks like this:

```
.
├── TheFile
└── tests
    ├── 4180
    │   └── data
    │       ├── bad
    │       └── good
    │           └── linebreaks.csv
    ├── get-rfc.sh
    ├── .git <contents omited>
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── README
    └── rfc4180.txt
```

I'm looking for a command that will output me:

```
TheFile
```

Comment: Is `find . | grep -v '\.git'` not efficient enough?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Are you asking to walk the tree, pruning away any parts that have a `.git` subdirectory? This is an easier problem than you asked - git has a `--git-dir` option so files can be tracked in repos which are not in the working tree.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve? As I understand it you want directories where there is no `.git` subdirectory and no parent directory has a `.git`either. Meaning the directory is not under version control and also is not ignored or uncommited.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens: You're correct, except that I don't want ignored and uncommited files (I think you meant "all files outside git repos and uncommited changes and ignored file in git repos", but I just want "all files outside git repos").

Comment: @icarus Thank you and you are correct, but I'm not sure how `--git-dir` connects to my question?

Comment: @pfnuesel That prunes all git data, but not the files in the directory containing the .git folder, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: `--git-dir` means that that you could have lots of files say in `~/sub/sub/directory` but the `.git` file for them could be in `/tmp`. When you were in `~/sub/sub/directory` you would need to give the extra argument every time to git, but it does mean there would be no sign of a `/git` file. Perhaps a slightly more realistic example might be that you have remote read-only access to a network drive hosting a project and want to track its changes in git.

Comment: @icarus That's a pretty nifty feature and I'll remember it, thanks for mentioning that, but for the sake of simplicity I'm not going to support it in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find the_starting_dir \( -type d -exec test -d '{}'/.git \; -prune \) -o -print
```

Not the most portable of find invocations, but works with GNU find.

Find walks the directory tree. The term `-prune` returns true but stops `find` from further processing the subtree. So the left hand side of the `-o` says "if this is a directory, and if `test` says there is a sub-directory called `.git` and if `prune` returns true then we are done processing this thing in the tree". The right hand side says "otherwise print it"

If you don't want directories printed then change `-print` to `\( ! -type d -print \)` but then you will not get any indication about empty directories.

You can change the `-print` to `-ls` to get listings, `-printf` [see manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html) etc etc.

Comment: That goes a long way! Two little things, one: this command also returns the root directory (`.`) along with the files not in git (i.e. `./test`), would there be a way to have `find` not output the `.`? Second: can find print full paths? I can pipe the result through `xargs -n 1 realpath -P` but then symlinks in the path are removed, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Change the `.` to the /full/path to get the absolute pathnames out. Change it to /full/path/* to give visible files/directories, or pipe to tail +1 to drop the first line of the output.

Comment: @Willem, please see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Comment: With `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` it gives `find: paths must precede expression: print` error. Changing `print` to `-print` fixes problem.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny Fixed

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you don't want to use git...

```
git status --untracked-files
```

**[edit]**

> As I understand the request, there is a directory tree. Inside this tree there are multiple git repos, but there is not one covering the whole tree. The example shows a git repo in the tests sub directory. Therefore your suggested command would get a git error fatal: Not in a git repository rather than TheFile as requested.

```
find . -name .git  -exec echo  $(realpath '{}') \; |\
sed 's/\(.*\)\(.git\)/git --git-dir=\1\2 --work-tree=\1 status --untracked-files/g' | bash
```

Comment: As I understand the request, there is a directory tree. Inside this tree there are multiple git repos, but there is not one covering the whole tree. The example shows a git repo in the tests sub directory. Therefore your suggested command would get a git error `fatal: Not in a git repository` rather than `TheFile` as requested. Of course an empty git repo could be created at the top level, in which case It would output the requested file and `tests/`, which could be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of specific cases in your request.

1. Files actually outside a git-managed directory.

   - Your `TheFile` fits this case.
2. Files inside a directory managed by Git, with some `.git` marker.
   `.git` is not always a directory. It can be a file as well, with a path to the real GIT_DIR. We can further break these files down as follows:

   1. Known files, those present in the Git index.
   2. Ignored files, those files matching a pattern per `gitignore(5)`:

      - `.gitignore`
      - `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`
      - `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`
   3. Files under an actual `$GIT_DIR` directory, but **NOT** part of the repo.

      - `.git/hooks` are the most likely
      - Could also be malware

So the most reliable case, is going to be generating TWO lists, relative to your given base directory `$D`, and comparing them (be sure to sort them and remove duplicates beforehand).

I can't think of a reliable way to generate the sub-list for 2.3 above, so I leave that as an open problem (I'd love to know about it, because I've lost hooks before).

Shell script to list known files per 2.1 above:

```
for g in $(find $D -name .git) ; do
  echo $g 
  p=${g%/.git} g2=`readlink -f $g` ;
  ( cd $p && GIT_DIR=$g2 \
  git ls-files --exclude-standard --full-name ) \
  | sed "s,^,${p}/,g" ; 
done > list-2.1
```

Shell script to list ignored files per 2.2 above:

```
for g in $(find $D -name .git) ; do
  p=${g%/.git} g2=`readlink -f $g` ;
  ( cd $p && GIT_DIR=$g2 \
  git ls-files \
  --others -i --exclude-standard ) \
  | sed "s,^,${p}/,g" ; 
done > list-2.2
```

Shell script to list files per 2.3 above:

```
TODO > list-2.3
```

Shell script to process the lists and find what's not on side B:

```
comm -23 <(find $D ! -type d |sort) <(sort 2.1 2.2 2.3 | uniq)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
find <root_dir> -type d -name ".git"
```

is this what you are looking for ?

you could also do something like

```
find <root_dir> -type d -name ".git" -print0 | xargs -0 -r dirname
```

to output just the directories names without the `/.git` part ; you can even avoid `dirname` and just use the output of `find` plus `/../` at the end of each folder name .

```
find <root_dir> -type d -name ".git" -print0 | xargs -0 -r printf "%s/../"
```

**EDIT**

You can negate the `-name` parameter and play with the `-maxdepth` value; for example I can easily list all the directories in my kernel tree that do not have a name that starts with a `c` ( uppercase or lowercase ) .

```
find linux-4.8.2/ -type d ! -iname "c*" -maxdepth 1
```

I still don't really get what you mean with :

> I'm looking for the exact opposite of this, namely a command which
>   find all files not in a Git repo;

simply because the files that are in the same directory on the same filesystem of the `.git` root dir might not be even be part of a repository, it just means that that literally there are files in the same dir ( or subdirs ) where there is a dir named `.git` too . Remember that `git` has the concept of *staging* and in general what you see on a disk may not be your git repository .

Take a look at https://libgit2.github.com/ which is the official C lib for git and there are a lot of bindings for it plus a lot of docs, examples and how to .

Comment: I'm looking for the exact opposite of this, namely a command which find all files not in a Git repo; this (a command which prints all GIt repos) I already have.

Comment: As an aside, `find . -type d -name .git -prune -print | xargs -n 1 dirname` is a lot faster. (Because the contents of the .git directories are not traversed through the `-prune`.)

Comment: @Willem I have updated my answer

Comment: I have a bunch of git repos, where I follow the convention of storing the .git metadata folder in the root of the folder containing all the repo's data. I assume my repos don't have files outside the repo folders. I have tooling to check the status of my repos, and I assume all files ignored by git were ignored for good reason by me.
Now, I want to find out what folders I forgot to put in a repo, and if you assume what I just did, this can be solved with: `find \( -type d -exec "test -d '{}/.git'" -prune \) -o -print`. That's what my question is about.